# How to check if date format is correct

Tags: java, datetime

I cannot write a method to test, whether the format of the date is correct.

I've written a method checking if the date format is correct, but it gives wrong results and I can't find a mistake.

```java
    boolean isDateFormatCorrect(String date) {
        LocalDate ld = null;
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        ld = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
        String result = ld.format(formatter);
        return result.equals(date);
    }
```

```java
    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({"2019-04-20", "2017-01-13"})
    void isDateFormatCorrect(String date) {
        assertThat(currencyService
                .isDateFormatCorrect(date))
                .isEqualTo(true);
    }
```

```java
    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({"20-04-2019", "01-01-1999", "22/2/2012", "2012/2/12"})
    void isDateFormatNotCorrect(String date) {
        assertThat(currencyService
                .isDateFormatCorrect(date))
                .isEqualTo(false);
    }
```

First test provides right answers, while 2nd one provides an exception:

```java
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20-04-2019' could not be parsed at index 0
```

I believe the answer is simple, but I've tried to fix it for over an hour and I've lost ideas.

Comment: Hmm, you pretty much need to catch the exception, mate.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect, but you're not doing anything with the exception the parsing can produce.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one.

```
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4, 4, SignStyle.NEVER)
            .appendPattern("MMdd")
            .toFormatter()
            .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)
```

Just to let you know the reason for exception is the invalid `date` component. Otherwise it is still a valid. For ex: `04-04-04` with `yyyy-MM-dd` is interpreted as 4th April 2004.

And this is Javadoc for [DatetimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for parsing year. Also see [ResolverStyle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html)

> Year: The count of letters determines the minimum field width below which padding is used. If the count of letters is two, then a reduced two digit form is used. For printing, this outputs the rightmost two digits. For parsing, this will parse using the base value of 2000, resulting in a year within the range 2000 to 2099 inclusive. If the count of letters is less than four (but not two), then the sign is only output for negative years as per SignStyle.NORMAL. Otherwise, the sign is output if the pad width is exceeded, as per SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD.